# Java 8 forEach not preserving order

Tags: lambda, foreach, java-8

I'm facing an issue where the Java 8 for-each loop is not preserving order while printing the data.
Basically, I'm printing a List of Set. The order of the list is not printing in order.

Please suggest if I can order the output without changing it to basic for-each loop.

**Code Sample:**

```
AtomicInteger row = new AtomicInteger(1);
//entities is a List
entities.forEach(entity -> {
    if (Optional.ofNullable(entity.getSet()).isPresent()) {
        entity.getSet().forEach(obj -> {
            try {
                int column = 0;
                addData(sheet, column++, row, nullToBlankString(entity.getName()));
                addData(sheet, column++, row, convertLongToString(obj.getLegNumber()));
                addData(sheet, column++, row, nullToBlankString(obj.getType()));
            } catch (WriteException e) {
                logger.error("Exception" + e.getCause().getMessage());
            }
            row.getAndIncrement();
        });
    }
});

private void addData(WritableSheet sheet, int column, AtomicInteger row, String s)
    throws RowsExceededException, WriteException {
    Label label;
    label = new Label(column, row.get(), s, times);
    sheet.addCell(label);
}
```

**Current Output:**
It prints the output without order.
[image]

**Expected Output:**
It should print the rows in the order of the LEG number
[image]

Comment: Is `entities` a List or a Set?

Comment: @Eran: entities is a List

Comment: This is a good example of how horrible code can become, when trying to use “Java 8 features” at all costs, without an actual understanding of their intention. Like writing `Optional.ofNullable(entity.getList()).isPresent()` instead of `entity.getList() != null` or kludging with an `AtomicInteger`, where ordinary loops would work smoothly. At least, it’s consistent with writing `nullToBlankString(null)` instead of `""`. But anyway—why do you check for the presence of `entity.getList()` but iterate over `entity.getSet()`?

Comment: @Holger: I've updated the code. It was a typo as I cannot paste the exact code here.

Comment: Creating a simplified example is fine, we even appreciate it, as long as you *try* the example yourself, to verify that it still is capable of reproducing the problem. Copying the example code from your IDE to the browser should not be able to introduce typos.

Comment: @Maverick You've said it's alist, but from the code we can see that you are iterating over a `Set`, which (unless is some ordered set) does not have an ordering: `entity.getSet().forEach(`

Comment: @Holger: I know.. this can be done without Java 8 features and it would be much simpler. I just wanted to check where it is causing the issue. I believe it's with
`AtomicInteger row = new AtomicInteger(1);
entities.forEach`

Comment: Can you provide evidence that the cell with the numbers 1,2,3,4,5 actually represent the row number and that the sheet.addCell method always positions the cell in the row represented by its row.get() constructor argument? Alternatively, can you just put System.out.println to convince yourself that the forEach call really does iterate in order and that the out-of-order problem is due to the way the cell gets positioned?

Comment: As said by others, depending on which actual `Set` type the method `entity.getSet()` returns, it is not maintaining an order.

Comment: Did you mean to put `row.getAndIncrement();` outside of the set's foreach loop but inadvertently put it inside?

Answer (score 0):

A set is normally unordered, especially the  most used HashSet.
Most lamba operations are allowed to execute in any order, possibly even in parallel.
A forEach directly on a list however performs in order.

Answer (score 0):

you should first sort the entities by legnumber
ex:

```
Collections.sort(entities, (o1, o2) -> o1.getLegNumber().compareTo(o2.getLegNumber()));
```